# How to know the RAM used by my application

Tags: android, eclipse

I want to know that how much RAM did the android app which I am developing is using of the device?

Is there any option in eclipse to know this?

Comment: http://developer.android.com/tools/debugging/debugging-memory.html

Comment: MAT plugin, from eclipse

Comment: Thanks all..I got my answer :)

Comment: @Ankush if you found an answer you're VERY encouraged to post the answer to your own question. As a bonus, you'll also receive a winter hat!

Comment: @STTLCU I used the MAT plugin.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to all...I got my answer. I used MAT plugin.